# Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x^4}$ for $x>0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

This is the first question that I am asking here and as the title says, I'm curious about the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x^4}$ for  $x>0$. If anybody can help with this, I'd greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: Use the [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) with $(1+x)^{1/2}$ and compose it with $x^4$. The series converges on a bounded set around $x=0$. Do you also need the series centered at points $a>0$?

Comment: Can you compute any term yourself ?

Comment: I think I found a solution for it, by factorising out $x^2$ and working with $x^2\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}$ we can use a standard Taylor Expansion and then substitute in the relevant terms.

Comment: Yes, that would give a series that converges for $|x|>1$. There cannot be a single power series converging on all of $x>0$ are once because $\sqrt{1+x^4}$ has singularities at the complex roots of $x^4+1$.

Comment: @AdrianZafari Why can't you do the same thing without factoring? You say you want a series for $x>0$, which is what the standard result gives you (until $x=1$, that is, because there is no Taylor series that works for all $x > 0$).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n $$
is fairly well-known and can be proved in many ways. By applying $\int_{0}^{z}(\ldots)\,dx$ to both sides we get
$$ \sqrt{1-z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n(1-2n)}\binom{2n}{n}z^n $$
then by replacing $z$ with $-x^4$ we have
$$ \sqrt{1+x^4} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n(1-2n)}\binom{2n}{n}x^{4n}.$$
The radius of convergence is $1$, of course, also because $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)}}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get such a series for *all* positive values of $x.$ What you may get will work for positive $x$ less than $1.$ You will have to check specially whether it works also when $x=1.$ In any case, we can definitely say that no such series exists for your function for $x>1.$

To explicitly compute this series, write your function as $$(1+x^4)^{1/2},$$ and use the binomial theorem to deduce that this is equal (in the range $|x|<1$) to the series $$1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1(1-2)(1-4)(1-6)\cdots(1-2k+2)}{2^kk!}(x^4)^k=1+\frac12x^4+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)(-3)(-5)\cdots(3-2k)}{2^kk!}x^{4k}.$$